# Convert list of tuples to sparse coo_matrix or sort it directly

Tags: python, sorting, scipy, sparse-matrix

My original problem was to sort a SciPy sparse `coo_matrix` named `weights`.

Before sorting it, it looked like:

```
  (0, 1)    2.0
  (0, 3)    4.0
  (1, 0)    5.0
  (3, 3)    1.0
  (0, 0)    5.0
  (2, 4)    1.0
  (1, 2)    2.0
  (1, 4)    2.0
  (0, 2)    3.0
  (0, 4)    1.0
  (2, 0)    5.0
  (4, 3)    3.0
  (3, 4)    3.0
  (2, 1)    0.0
  (3, 0)    5.0
  (3, 2)    0.0
  (2, 2)    0.0
  (4, 4)    0.0
  (4, 0)    0.0
  (3, 1)    2.0
```

I want to have the following (end-)result

```
  (0, 0)    5.0
  (0, 1)    2.0
  (0, 2)    3.0
  (0, 3)    4.0
  (0, 4)    1.0
  (1, 0)    5.0
  (1, 2)    2.0
  (1, 4)    2.0
  (2, 0)    5.0
  (2, 1)    0.0
  (2, 2)    0.0
  (2, 4)    1.0
  (3, 0)    5.0  
  (3, 1)    2.0
  (3, 2)    0.0
  (3, 3)    1.0 
  (3, 4)    3.0
  (4, 0)    0.0
  (4, 3)    3.0
  (4, 4)    0.0
```

What I tried to do so:

```
weights_tuples = zip(weights.row, weights.col, weights.data)
sorted_weights_tuples = sorted(train_weights_tuples, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
```

This did sort it, but didn't result in the right output format:

```
[(0, 0, 5.0), (0, 1, 2.0), (0, 3, 4.0), (0, 4, 1.0), (1, 1, 4.0), (1, 2, 2.0), (1, 4, 2.0), (2, 0, 5.0), (2, 1, 0.0), (2, 2, 0.0), (2, 3, 0.0), (3, 0, 5.0), (3, 1, 2.0), (3, 2, 0.0), (3, 3, 1.0), (3, 4, 3.0), (4, 0, 0.0), (4, 1, 0.0), (4, 2, 2.0), (4, 3, 3.0)]
```

My question is, how to convert the gained result into the right format, or whether there is a better way to sort the `coo_matrix` to directly get the right output format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `coo` uses `lexsort` on `row` and `col` when converting to `csr`.  Covert the `csr` back to `coo` to get the sorted values.  `weights.sum_duplicates()` is an in-place operation that does this lexsort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@hpaulj's comment gives the relevant hint, but here's how to make use of this without relying on implementation details of the methods on `coo_matrix`, and without the overhead of converting to CSR:

First, use `np.lexsort` to get the permutation giving rise to the right order, then create a new `coo_matrix` using the initializer which takes as input the sparse representation:

```py
order = np.lexsort((weights.col, weights.row))
sorted_weights = coo_matrix((weights.data[order], (weights.row[order], weights.col[order])),
                            shape=weights.shape)
```

If you don't mind making your code a bit more obscure, you might be able to squeeze out a bit of performance by replacing `np.lexsort` with

```py
np.argsort(N * rows + cols)
```

where `N` is the number of rows.

Note that, as @hpaulj also says in his comment, `coo_matrix.sum_duplicates` does this inplace, and it sets `coo_matrix.has_canonical_format` accordingly to indicate that the rows and columns have been sorted. However, in the implementation of `sum_duplicates`, `weights.col` and `weights.row` have been swapped in the call to `np.lexsort`, so using that out of the box would net you the opposite of what you want. This also means that the flag `has_canonical_format` in fact does not determine a unique format, which is [already noted as a bug on GitHub](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10050).